# Some data is getting missed while converting an object into string in android

Tags: android, string, http

I am fetching a URL from an object using this code:

```
 try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
      JSONObject obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
      System.out.println("INSIDE URL>>> "+obj.get("url")); 

      Object image =obj.get("url");
      System.out.println("INSIDE OBJECT IMAGE>>> "+obj.get("url")); 

      editor.putString("IMAGE_URL",image.toString() );
      // editor.putString("IMAGE_URL","its working");

      editor.commit();
```

The problem is that when I convert an object which contains URLto string, one third of URL is going missing:

```
     System.out(11948): INSIDE OBJECT >>> https://demo_urljfj_jdjhhhgfx_jjdhg_jjfhhfb__1514719142_n.jpg?oh=abe04e95f14532d11f981678518cdd&oe=54BEFBC&__gda__=14213331_e0b6c1dc2a741de680afd0f8a9c370
```

Becomes:

```
     https://demo_urljfj_jdjhhhgfx_jjdhg_jjfhhfb__1514719142_n
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: btw you can use LogCat for the logs

Comment: Where is the source of the Json (web, local file, ...)? What is the encoding of the source (utf-8, ...)? If you remove the dot before "jpg", does the rest of the string appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all thank you Guys for taking your valuable time for answering my question . Some how i managed to find answer for my question.

```
    Object image =obj.get("url");
    System.out.println("INSIDE OBJECT IMAGE>>> "+obj.get("url")); 
    editor.putString("IMAGE_URL",image.toString() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with obj.getString("url");

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String image =obj.getString("url");
System.out.println("INSIDE OBJECT IMAGE>>> "+obj.getString("url"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this!

```
int cnt= jsonarr.length();

for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{ 
      String url=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
}
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!